# WinRT Extract frame from video as image

Tags: windows, video, windows-runtime

I'm building a Windows 8 application involving some video processing. Right now I'm stuck on extracting a frame from a .mp4 video clip as a BitmapImage. The two examples I've been looking at online are [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/windows-8-metro-style-app-development-using-winrt-from-c) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hi-IN/winappswithcsharp/thread/c7e716f7-9b1b-4562-912f-5fde0d97f9a3), but I'm getting an exception when trying to create the BitmapDecoder. I've pasted the code I've got so far below, but mind you I have no idea what I'm doing.

```
    public async void Extract_Image_From_Video(StorageFile video_file)
    {

        // Create image
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

        // Open the video file as a stream
        IRandomAccessStream readStream = await video_file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

        // Breaks here 
        BitmapDecoder bmpDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(readStream);

        BitmapFrame frame = await bmpDecoder.GetFrameAsync(0);

        BitmapTransform bmpTrans = new BitmapTransform();

        bmpTrans.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Cubic;

        PixelDataProvider pixelDataProvider = await frame.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, bmpTrans, ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);

        byte[] pixelData = pixelDataProvider.DetachPixelData();

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, ras);
        // write the pixel data to our stream
        enc.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, 200, 200, bmpDecoder.DpiX, bmpDecoder.DpiY, pixelData);

        await enc.FlushAsync();

        // this is critical and below does not work without it!
        ras.Seek(0);

        // Set to the image
        image.SetSource(ras);

        // PreviewImage is an image control defined in the xaml
        PreviewImage.Source = gridImage;
    }
```

Comment: good question I'm having similar issues.

Comment: AFAIK the BitmapDecoder class works only with still images so feeding it with a MP4 stream won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I created a c++ project for this which can be used by a c# app. check out [this](http://shivamcv.blogspot.in/)

Comment: do you still have solution? no github page